# Using a custom class loader for a module dependency in SBT

Tags: scala, sbt, classloader

I have a multi-module SBT build consisting of `api`, `core` and `third-party`. The structure is roughly this:

```
api
|- core
|- third-party
```

The code for `third-party` implements `api` and is copied verbatim from somewhere else, so I don't really want to touch it.

Because of the way `third-party` is implemented (heavy use of singletons), I can't just have `core` depend on `third-party`. Specifically, I only need to use it via the `api`, but I need to have multiple, isolated copies of `third-party` at runtime. (This allows me to have multiple "singletons" at the same time.)

If I'm running outside of my SBT build, I just do this:

```
def createInstance(): foo.bar.API = {
  val loader = new java.net.URLClassLoader("path/to/third-party.jar", parent)
  loader.loadClass("foo.bar.Impl").asSubclass(classOf[foo.bar.API]).newInstance()
}
```

But the problem is that I don't know how to figure out at runtime what I should give as an argument to `URLClassLoader` if I'm running via `sbt core/run`.

Comment: 1. How do you intend to bundle the project? sbt-assembly? Or is the third-party.jar going to be external?
2. What form are the third-party singletons? object? I ask because you mention .newInstance()

Comment: @DaleWijnand 1. Haven't decided yet, but it's likely that I'll let `sbt-assembly` bundle `api`, `core` and the Scala library and `third-party.jar` separately.

Comment: @DaleWijnand 2. It's rather complicated. Basically, the third party library manages some external process. It can handle many of these processes at once, but needs to be initialized. Upon initialization, it populates a map inside an object (i.e. a literal Scala `object`), e.g. the path to the external process. My code needs to be able to deal with multiple locations of that external process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work, though I didn't quite tested it with your setup.

The basic idea is to let sbt write the classpath into a file that you
can use at runtime. [sbt-buildinfo](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo)
already provides a good basis for this, so I'm gonna use it here, but you
might extract just the relevant part and not use this plugin as well.

Add this to your project definition:

```
lazy val core = project enablePlugins BuildInfoPlugin settings (
  buildInfoKeys := Seq(BuildInfoKey.map(exportedProducts in (`third-party`, Runtime)) {
    case (_, classFiles) ⇒ ("thirdParty", classFiles.map(_.data.toURI.toURL)) 
  })
  ...
```

At runtime, use this:

```
def createInstance(): foo.bar.API = {
  val loader = new java.net.URLClassLoader(buildinfo.BuildInfo.thirdParty.toArray, parent)
  loader.loadClass("foo.bar.Impl").asSubclass(classOf[foo.bar.API]).newInstance()
}
```

`exportedProducts` only contains the compiled classes for the project (e.g. `.../target/scala-2.10/classes/`). Depending on your setup, you might want to use `fullClasspath` instead
(which also contains the libraryDependencies and dependent projects) or any other classpath related key.

Comment: That sounds great, I'll try it out.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Your solution did indeed work, thanks.